# How to call function each day for the next 7 days (not more) using @nestjs/scheduler

Tags: javascript, nestjs, scheduled-tasks

I want to call a function each day(24 hours) starting from the current time but it runs for only 7 days not more!
I am using Nestjs (@nestjs/scheduler)

```
@Cron(new Date(Date.now() + (24*60*60*1000) * 7)
function() {
  console.log("This should get called each day during the next 7 days")
}
```

I tried to read [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#dynamic-intervals) but I couldn't figure out how to perform such thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  startTime = new Date().getTime();
  @Cron(`* * 0-23/24 * * *`, {
    name: 'myJob',
  })
  handleCron() {
    console.log(`Called every day for the next 7 days`);
    this.closeJob();
  }

  closeJob() {
    const job = this.schedulerRegistry.getCronJob('myJob');

    const endTime = this.startTime + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

    if (job.lastDate().getTime() > endTime) {
      job.stop();
    }
  }
```